# Friendslist doesn't work anymore after the powerful access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the `friends list` of `Facebook Developer`.
I have the `access_token` with the access to `user_friends` and `read_friendslist` and the fetch was working fine.
I go here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0

And I use `me/friends` after the creation of the `access_token`. All ok.

So, I tried to get an `access_token` more powerful, selecting all the voices.
Unfortunately, now I can fetch only two friends of my friendslist.
If I delete my `access_token` and I create a new one, the result is the same: only two friends.

What can I do to retrieve the entire list as before?
I think that this is a privacy setting of the application, but `Graph API Explorer` has the privacy on "Friends" in my list of applications.

EDIT

this is a screenshot: http://oi58.tinypic.com/290yecx.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook changed a lot of things recently, for privacy reasons you can only get the friends who are also using the App now. See here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/

Comment: This may be true, but the changes in my situation are happened in few minutes:
I tried the command and it worked, so I tried the powerful access_token and it worked. When I returned on the previous access_token, the API gave me only two friends.

Comment: could have been a glitch before, or the app got updated to v2.0. you could try adding "/v1.0/{object}" to every call, but i dunno if that works. in any case, the result you get now is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v2.0 of the Graph API, you'll NOT be able to get the whole friend list via `/me/friends` anymore!

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Quote:

> In Graph API v2.0, access to /me/friends is no longer part of the
>   default (public_profile) permissions. We now require you to ask for
>   the new permission user_friends. With this permission, /me/friends now
>   returns the person's friends who are also using the app.